# New to CodeIgniter and I don't know how to edit db

Tags: php, sql, forms, codeigniter, edit

So I'm trying to learn how to use CI and the person who wants me to learn it said its easier to use it without a model just with controlers and views. I'm trying to edit a row from my DB . Here is my controler code

```
public function index() {
    $alimente = $this->db->query('select alimente.id, alimente.name FROM alimente order by name asc')->result();
    $totalQuery = $this->db->query("select count(id) as total from alimente")->result();

    $nrcrt = 1;
    foreach ($alimente as $a) {
        $a->nrcrt = $nrcrt++;
    }
    $content = $this->parser->parse('alimente/list_alimente', array("ALIMENTE" => $alimente, "COUNT" => $totalQuery), true);
    $TITLE = " Lista Alimente";
    $array = array('TITLE' => $TITLE, 'CONTENT' => $content);
    $this->parser->parse('TEST', $array, false);

}

public function add() {
    $add_aliment = $this->parser->parse('alimente/add_aliment', array(), true);
    $TITLE = "Adauga alimente";
    $array = array('TITLE' => $TITLE, 'CONTENT' => $add_aliment);
    $this->parser->parse('TEST', $array, false);
}

public function add_done() {
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
    );

    $this->db->insert('alimente', $data);

    redirect("alimente");
}

public function edit($id) {
    $alimente = $this->db->query('select alimente.id, alimente.name FROM alimente  WHERE id = "' . $id . '" order by name desc')->result();
    $content = $this->parser->parse('alimente/edit_alimente', array("ALIMENTE" => $alimente), true);
    $TITLE = "Modifica";
    $array = array('TITLE' => $TITLE, 'CONTENT' => $content);
    $this->parser->parse('TEST', $array, false);
}

public function edit_done() {
    $name  = $this->imput->post("name");
    $id  = $this->imput->post("id");

    $query = $this->db->prepare("update alimente set name = '".$name."' where id = '".$id."'")->result();
    $query->execute($name, $id);

    redirect("alimente");
}
```

And here is my views file

```
<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2">Modifica alimente</h1>
</div>

<form method="post" action="{SITE_URL}/alimente/edit_done">

    <div class="form-group">

        {ALIMENTE}    
        <label> Id aliment</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" value= " {id} " class="form-control" />
        <label> Nume aliment</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value= " {name} " class="form-control" />
        <br>
        {/ALIMENTE}
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Modifica" name="name" class="btn btn-primary" />

</form>
```

Any help would be great, and I'm sorry if the code is horrible, I just started learning programing for 3 months

EDIT : I forgot to put the error I'm getting

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Alimente::$imput
>
> Filename: controllers/Alimente.php
>
> Line Number: 49
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgnite\application\controllers\Alimente.php
>   Line: 49 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgnite\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function post() on null
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgnite\application\controllers\Alimente.php
>
> Line Number: 49
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgnite\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: `imput` is spellt `input`

Comment: And `spellt` is spelled `spelt` or `spelled` :-)  https://www.grammarly.com/blog/spelled-spelt/

Comment: I'm so stupid for typing it like that, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all CI is a MVC framework so all the database related things should go to models.
if you try to access the database from controller or from view. This is a voilation of archetecture and its not a good practise to access the database from controller.  TRY creating seperate file for example

employee.php (html) where all the html will go in applciaiton/view folder
Employee.php (controller )where all the url method will hit and from there it will call appropiate method from model . will go in applciaiton/controller folder

Employee_model (model) where all the functions to insert update and delete into database will be fine in model.

I will recommend you to watch some tutorials to understand the concept of MVC

Comment: Could you recommand me a good tutorial ? I know its best practice to use MVC but the person who asked me to do this simple project told me its far easier for me to just use views and controllers. {This does not help me when I get stuck and try to find help online }

Answer (score 0):

> Change **imput**  into **input** then try

```
public function edit_done() {
$name  = $this->input->post("name");
$id  = $this->input->post("id");

$query = $this->db->prepare("update alimente set name = '".$name."' where id = '".$id."'")->result();
$query->execute($name, $id);

redirect("alimente");
```

}